# Review queues not working?

Tags: support

Is there a problem with the First Post and Late Answer review queues?

They both seem suspiciously empty today.  The other queues are fine as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

No bug - just a really slow day for review activity.  It happens sometimes - take a break.

Answer (score 1):

They were working fine for me, earlier. Maybe my continued use of them caused them to be emptied ;-))